# tFPDF add multiple DejaVu fonts

Tags: php, fonts, fpdf

How would one use multiple styles of DejaVu fonts when using tFPDF?

I would like to use the *DejaVuSans* font for some text and *DejaVuSansMono* for other.

The tutorial  shows you can include font like this:`$pdf -> AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSans.ttf',true);` and then use it like `$pdf -> SetFont("DejaVu","",10);`

But if I add additional font `$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansMono.ttf',true);` nothing changes.

So how do I specify where I want to use the Mono font and where the default one?

My code currently looks like this (doesn't work):

```
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSans.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont("DejaVu","",10);
$pdf->Cell(10,10 , "sometext");

$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansMono.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont("DejaVu","",10);
$pdf->Cell(10,10 , "sometext");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For anyone still interested in an answer*

You only need to `AddFont` once:

```
$pdf->AddFont('dejavusans', '', 'DejaVuSans.ttf', true);
$pdf->AddFont('dejavusans', 'B', 'DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf', true);
$pdf->AddFont('dejavusans', 'I', 'DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf', true);
$pdf->AddFont('dejavusans', 'BI', 'DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf', true);
```

Then, when using a font for a piece of text, use it like this:

```
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 9);
```

or

```
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', 'I', 10);
```

So, only AddFont once, and then SetFont them where you need them. I tried using other names than 'dejavusans', but that did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add fonts as below:

```
// Add a Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu', '', 'DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf', true);
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu', 'B', 'DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf', true);
```